# Formatting list of Amazon EC2 instances from the command line

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

I retrieve data about my current Amazon EC2 instances with `ec2-describe-instances -H`, which returns something like the following:

```
Type    ReservationID   Owner   Groups  Platform
RESERVATION r-xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxx    default
INSTANCE    i-xxxxxxxx  ami-2b5fba42    ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal running user    0       m1.small    2011-07-12T21:15:39+0000    us-east-1a  aki-xxxxxxxx    ari-xxxxxxxx        monitoring-disabled xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx         instance-store          paravirtual xen     sg-xxxxxxxx default
```

This looks messy in the OS X terminal. How can I make this output more readable?

Comment: may be store the output in a `.txt` file and see it, it should be NEAT :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just whipped up a little bash/awk script you might be interested in:

https://github.com/epheph/fec2din

It displays EC2 instance output in the format of:

```
Instance: i-57192e11
AMI: ami-a7f539ce
Type: t1.micro
Public IP: 50.99.41.60 (ec2-50-99-41-60.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
Private IP: 10.99.241.197
Public Key: production
Start Time: 2011-11-09
Security Group: production
Block Devices:
    /dev/sda1
    /dev/sdj
    /dev/sdk
```

Answer (score 3):

What specific portions would you like to see, or view?

```
 ec2-describe-instances | grep INSTANCE | awk {'print $4'}
```

This will give you the instance name, which would be `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` in your example.

**Edit**

As the person asking the question said they wanted it in a *cleaner format* ... without specifying what that is ... here is my feeble attempt:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 tmpFile="/tmp/ec2.info"
 ec2Info=`ec2-describe-instances > $tmpFile`
 instances=`cat $tmpFile | grep TAG | awk {'print $3'}`
 numOfInstances=`cat $tmpFile | grep INSTANCE | wc -l`
 you=`whoami`


 echo "Dear $you, I wanted to describe for you the current number of instances you have: $numOfInstances"
 echo "The instances you have, by hostname, are as follows ..."
 for instance in $instances
 do
      hostname=`cat $tmpFile | grep INSTANCE | grep $instance | awk {' print $4 '}`
      echo "$hostname"
 done
```

*small disclaimer* the above code may not be perfect ... it's to give the person asking the question the right information to make a "clean format" however they see fit.

Comment: I was hoping to view all of the data in a cleaner format, but this solves the problem in a different way. Thanks!

Comment: I'm imagining something like the [command for vertical output of MySQL query results](http://www.linuxask.com/questions/vertical-g-output-of-query-result-in-mysql-client).

Comment: Thanks! Note the `i` is missing from `instances` on line 5 (tried editing it but there's a 6 character minimum).